# LDMFD affects R13 oddly

Tags: arm, ucos

We are using arm9 with ucos. The `OS_CPU_ARM_ExceptHndlr_BrkTask` common porting function's last instrument has strange behavior in our system.

```
Instrument: LDMFD SP!,{R0-R12,LR,PC}^
```

Let's suppose the SP is 0x10002000, and the following 15 DWORDs (which will be copied to R0-R12, LR, PC) have values from 1 to 15.  We find the PC (R15) is changed and jumps to 15, but the SP (R13) is changed to a strange value (an address far outside the stack memory space).  I expected it would become 0x1000203C (0x10002000+4*15).

Why is R13 changed this way?

Comment: `SP` is `R13`. `R14` is `LR`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is a spell mistake, it is R13 that been affected. I have change question to R13.

Answer (score 0):

This instruction loads `r14`, like the other registers, from the stack. Write to PC causes the jump. This is not a branch and link that would set the return address to the link register.

Additionally, this instruction is actually an exception return (Because of the ^). So depending on the mode you are returning from, `r14` might be banked. So after the exception return, you might see a different `r14` than the one that was loaded from memory.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The question have a spell mistake which have been fixed. The R13(SP) is the register that have odd behavior.

Comment: @shino, the above answer still applies. The stack pointer is banked, so you need to understand if you're seeing `R13_irq` or `R13_usr` for example.